# PHP mysql affected rows returns 0 even if query updates

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have created a REST API for the first time and I am having issues with update query.
I logged the client body and the server is receiving the right informations. The issue seems to be with the sql.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE leveling_accounts SET `status`=? WHERE license_key = ? AND username = ? AND `password` = ? AND region = ? AND list_name = ? AND id=? AND unique_address=?");
$stmt>bind_param("ssssssis",$information['status'],$license_key,$information['username'],$information['password'],$information['region'],$information['list_name'],$information['acc_id'],$information['unique_address']);
$stmt->execute();
$affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
$stmt->close();
if($affected_rows>0)
{
    $response = new Response("Account has been successfully updated!");
    $response->echoResponse();
    http_response_code(200);
    exit();
}
else
{
    $response = new Response("Account has not been updated!");
    $response->echoResponse();
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
}
```

For some reason the client is receiving `Account has not been updated!`, even with receiving correct values from the client.

Comment: Why not to debug this? Add
`if ($this->conn->errno) die("Error: {$this->conn->error}");` before `if($affected_rows>0)`

Comment: I echod out errno and it returns 0, which means it doesn't have any issues.

Comment: Just remove that affected rows condition. I don't see how it makes any sense. Why would you send 400 status? What's wrong with a request? What makes you think you need this condition at all?

Comment: And for goodness sake, **remove** that horrible stuff suggested by @MuradAli. That's NOT how you check for errors. It has to be done on connect https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting

Comment: Yeah, but how do I know if everything went good then? Like this the client knows to try again.

Comment: You are right, the 400 status was used badly. I have removed what you suggested and only send out 400 if the request is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If if something goes wrong, then mysqli will throw an error. As long as there is no error, **everything went good**.